# Call function to get data and navigate to link on data arrival

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a situation where I should get a song item by id to get the path for that song, and then navigate to that song on button click.

Is there any specific hook that can be used to navigate on data arrival, useEffect will be called any time that state changes but the problem is that first needs to be dispatched the action to get the song, check if it returns any item and then navigate. Typically if it is has been published on the list, it should exist on the db, but the problem might be at the API side, so that check `results.length > 0` is why that check is necessary.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleClick = (myId: string) => {
    dispatch(SongActions.searchSong(myId));
    if (results.length > 0) {
      if (Object.keys(results[0]).length > 0) {
        // navigate(`/songs/${results[0].myPath}`);
      }
    }
  }
}, [dispatch, results])
```

When user clicks on list item which has a song title, it should call the function `handleClick(id)` with id of the song as parameter, that is to get the metadata of the song, src path etc.

```js
<Typography onClick={() => handleClick(songItem.songId)} sx={styles.songListItemText}>{songItem.Title}</Typography>
```

#### Edit

And this is how I have setup the `searchSong` action:

```js
searchSong: (obj: SearchSongInputModel): AppThunk<SearchPayload> => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    payload: { isLoading: true },
    type: SearchActionType.REQUEST,
  });
  try {
    const response = await SearchApi.searchSongAsync(obj);
    if (response.length === 0) {
      toast.info(`No data found: ${obj.SongId}`)
    }
    dispatch({
      type: SearchActionType.RECEIVED_SONG,
      payload: { results: response },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error: ", e);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  But what *is* clear is that you can't define a function within the `useEffect` callback and expect it to exist outside of that scope.  If `handleClick` needs to be invoked by an element in the markup then it needs to be defined in the component.  (Surely there's an error in the browser console...)

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the code is not functional. I was just trying to explain, that I need to be able to call `handleClick` function, but I need also `useEffect` to make the navigation on state change.

Comment: Those are two different operations, they shouldn't be combined.  Whatever should happen when clicking on the element would go in the `handleClick` function which would be defined in the component.  Whatever should happen in response to a state change would happen in a `useEffect`.

Comment: Is there any way to know on `handleClick` if the data from the dispatched function has arrived so that I can call navigate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing up the purpose of the `useEffect` hook and asynchronous event handlers like button element's `onClick` handlers. The `useEffect` hook is to meant to issue intentional side-effects in response to *some* dependency value updating and is tied to the React component lifecycle, while `onClick` handlers/etc are meant to respond to asynchronous events, i.e. a user clicking a button. They don't mix.

Assuming `SongActions.searchSong` is an asynchronous action, you've correctly setup Redux middleware to handle them (*i.e. Thunks*), ***and*** the action returns the fetched response data, then the dispatched action returns a Promise that the callback can wait for.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleClick = async (myId: string) => {
  const results = await dispatch(SongActions.searchSong(myId));
  if (results.length > 0 && Object.keys(results[0]).length > 0) {
    navigate(`/songs/${results[0].myPath}`);
  }
};

...

<Typography
  onClick={() => handleClick(songItem.songId)}
  sx={styles.songListItemText}
>
  {songItem.Title}
</Typography>
```

The `searchSong` action creator should return a resolved value for consumers to await for.

```
searchSong: (obj: SearchSongInputModel): AppThunk<SearchPayload> => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startRequest());
  try {
    const results = await SearchApi.searchSongAsync(obj);
    if (!results.length) {
      toast.info(`No data found: ${obj.SongId}`)
    }
    dispatch(receivedSong({ results }));
    return results; // <-- return resolved value here
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error: ", e);
  } finally {
    dispatch(completeRequest());
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot await any results from my action. You can see the post how I have setup the `searchSong` action.

Comment: @Sachihiro You certain can `await` a Thunk function. It looks like the issue might be that no *value* is returned. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a state such as `const [isDataPresent, setIsDataPresent] = useState(false)` to keep track of if the data has arrived or not. And as David has mentioned in the comments you cannot call the function inside the `useEffect` on `handleClick`. Instead what you can do is create that function outside the `useEffect` hook and inside the same function you fetch the data and check if the data is at all present, if present then you can set the above boolean state to true and then redirect from that function itself.

Since you are already fetching the data from the same API and different endpoint, what you can do is -

1. Create a new component.
2. Since you are mapping over the data send the data to this component by rendering it inside the map function. It'd allow the data to be passed and components to be rendered one by one.
3. Create a state in the new component.
4. Use `useEffect` hook to fetch the data for a single song since when you are passing the data from the previous component to this one you would also get access to the ID and store it inside the state. This would be occurring inside the newly created component.

Comment: Inside `handleClick` function, will check only once for the data if present, that is my bottleneck

Comment: But you need data at the click of a button for a song. Fetching the data can be done in useEffeect hook and stored in the state as well as set the boolean value to true and in handleClick function when the id is passed to the function it can use the find function to find the song you need and then check for the presence of data if present then redirects it.

Comment: The list of songs can be long, fetching and storing all data without demand I think is inefficient.

Comment: How are you planning on getting the id of the song then? You obviously need to fetch them to render the data using a map and then only you can get the id of the song then?

Comment: API is built in a way that I can fetch the list of songs, and that has minimal info, to get more info for each song, I need to fetch that particular song with a given Id.

Comment: Are you passing the id from another component to this one?

Comment: No, I am rendering a list of songs, but on click of a list item, I want to navigate to that single song, display. But I need to get the path of the song from that data that will arrive from `dispatch(SongActions.searchSong(myId));`

Comment: You are rendering a list of songs using the same API right which gets all the songs?

Comment: Yes it is from the same API, different endpoints

Comment: That is what I was saying then. Send the data on click with the ID from the fetched data since you might be mapping to show it and then fetch the data using the above method in the answer inside another useEffect with the same dependencies in the array store it in the state and then on clicking just check if data is present or not and if present then redirect it from the handleClick function which should not be inside any useEffect.

Comment: can you write some pseudocode?